# Help with Joins please - Where on a CASE field?

Tags: sql, join

tblSource  - has ActionID, SourceName, and SourceID
tblX - has ActionCode and SourceName
lkuActionCode - has both.

I also need the CASE, because ActionCodes in tblX are different from ActionCodes in lkuActionCode....

I am trying ti display SourceID, ActionID, and everything else from tblX in one query...

right now i'm getting an error: Invalid column name 'newAction2'. on the last line... please help

```
select  t2.Sourceid, t1.actionCode , t3.ActionID
CASE   
WHEN  t1.actionCode  = 'R' THEN 'N' END AS newAction2
from tblSource t2 
right join  tblX t1 on t1.SourceName= t2.SourceName
right join lkuActionCode t3 on t3.actioncode = newAction2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select  t2.Sourceid, t1.actionCode , t3.ActionID,

CASE WHEN  t1.actionCode  = 'R' THEN 'N' END AS newAction2

from tblSource t2 
right join  tblX t1 on t1.SourceName= t2.SourceName
right join lkuActionCode t3
       on t3.actioncode = CASE WHEN t1.actionCode  = 'R' THEN 'N' END
```

However, LEFT JOINs are usually preferable to avoid confusion later. Or you even need OUTER JOINs?

```
select
    t2.Sourceid, t1.actionCode , t3.ActionID,
    CASE WHEN t1.actionCode  = 'R' THEN 'N' END AS newAction2
from
    lkuActionCode t3
    LEFT JOIN
    tblX t1 on t3.actioncode = CASE WHEN 1.actionCode  = 'R' THEN 'N' END
    LEFT JOIN
    tblSource t2 t1.SourceName= t2.SourceName
```

Comment: your first example worked great. but some of the action codes in my lkuActionCodes do not show up on the tblSource... so now i get 5 extra null records with those action codes, how can i only show those that do exist in tblSource?

Comment: @xrum: remove "RIGHT" from the join

Answer (score 2):

You can't reference newAction2 in the join statement. Try repeating the case in the join, like this:

```
select 
   t2.Sourceid
  ,t1.actionCode
  ,t3.ActionID
  CASE   
    WHEN t1.actionCode = 'R' THEN 'N'
  END AS newAction2
from tblSource t2 
right join tblX t1
  on t1.SourceName= t2.SourceName
right join lkuActionCode t3
  on t3.actioncode = CASE   
    WHEN t1.actionCode = 'R' THEN 'N'
  END
```

Do you want the actionCodes that aren't R to come through unmodified? If so:

```
select 
   t2.Sourceid
  ,t1.actionCode
  ,t3.ActionID
  CASE   
    WHEN t1.actionCode = 'R' THEN 'N'
    ELSE t1.actionCode
  END AS newAction2
from tblSource t2 
right join tblX t1
  on t1.SourceName= t2.SourceName
right join lkuActionCode t3
  on t3.actioncode = CASE   
    WHEN t1.actionCode = 'R' THEN 'N'
    ELSE t1.actionCode
  END
```

You could also use a subquery to only make the case statement once:

```
 select 
   t2.Sourceid
  ,t1.actionCode
  ,t3.ActionID
  ,fixedActionCode.actionCode
from tblSource t2 
right join tblX t1
  on t1.SourceName= t2.SourceName
right join (
  SELECT
     CASE
       WHEN t1.actionCode = 'R' THEN 'N'
       ELSE t1.actionCode
     END as actionCode
    ,otherField1
    ,otherField2  
  FROM lkuActionCode     
) as fixedActionCode
  on t3.actioncode = fixedActionCode.actionCode
```

Comment: Hah, yep. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just Mapping the one value you could make the join expression

```
  ON t3.actioncode = 'N' 
   AND t1.actionCode = 'R'
```